# Почему не работает перезагрузка метода?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Я имею такой код:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqBDAzgazc1AXjgCIpgYBXKAOzjCggDNgssBLCGrEgbgCh+AYwA22LHABCEGPwDe-OHGyIaQuAHMKAJVaRuwaTAAUMUDABccLDCjsaGgJRWACowC27LMAA8Nuw4AfAJKKmqaOnpc3kY+aHDmwDQAJhKYuPgocAA+cJQpwEz2wMmBpuZW-vYaADQI2DgA-FZoznBuEJ7ecQkgZikSZBTUdAzMrBzRJI3WttUA2gC6cJVzQYpwCkpK5FS0ygDuGOzwkDY9iQOkuyP0jCxsnNwkcDNVDksrswEaZY4bAF9+ED+Ex8kIYE96BBzmg-q4PF5fHD5BsbvsOl1gAA6chYCAiABuwGMJBe2HQ-xBQmi8AARjI4MQaMADlIZMZ-vwGTBsVoYLosPoYhySGYbCR-gB6KVKAB6jUEPL5kSF0UMovFMBIdSGe1G9wmTx40tlcAVQA)

```typescript
export type TaskType = "return professions";

class Bot
{
  async getResponseBot(text: string): Promise<string>;
  async getResponseBot<T extends TaskType | undefined>(text: string, task?: T): Promise<T extends "return professions"? string[] : string>
  {
    return await post<T extends "return professions" ? string[] : string>()
  }
}

function post<T>(): Promise<T>
{
  return Promise.resolve("" as T)
}

const bot = new Bot()

bot.getResponseBot("test")
//  ^?

bot.getResponseBot("test", "return professions")
//  ^?
```

Почему-то я не могу передать вторым параметром текст, пишет, что ожидается один аргумент, что я делаю не так?

---

Получается я должен делать что-то [такое](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgZwNY3NAvFARAJwsAVxwDsowcB7AMwgQQEsLiEsoAfbPQkqAIwooAbCHGJYA3AChJAY0GIEUAEIVgkgN6SoURCGIyoAc3wAlWmCYIIK4AApgEAB7AAXFATAc9YoYCUbgAVKAFt6KwAeDy8fAD4tHQQ9A2NgMwQLZmtVeydXd09vQwAaKGBEJDdcfCJScmpaBkssfyggilCIqMKAbQBdOO1dfSNTc0ssuwdnNy6fErLkSq4avgFhUWbAkLCIcP4hEWIBhKSR1LHMmxzp-Oji0vKAfjd4ZFRIFraO3dnDdluer1-vt1kd4pptNpljw4AB3OD0YBkCgeSIFHx9f6-YFrQ4xWy+eIAX0kJMkVAI+mAjFqKOA4Rg+M+2wijI08WhpC+OwAdHgEEIAG4QWxYViIWCEskySxI-hIzDECCw5TZQmSeU8lJpDJWK5YBweZqSAD0Ju0AD1HtJNdqLnrsgbaMAsCUqtxapQaHQaSxCWbLdaNaotaN0uN9YaXW7OasDht-eaoFagA)?

Comment: А я предупреждал, что всякие попытки с исключением перегрузок и попыткой вывести тип из входного параметра - приведут к большим проблемам. Лучше использовать по аналогии с другими языками и завершить методом реализации для всех возможных вариантов. Этот последний метод только для реализации, а что он там возвращает совершенно не важно, TS его не увидит.

Comment: [Без всяких extends](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqBDAzgazc1AXjgCIpgYBXKAOzjCggDNgssBLCGrEgbgCh+AYwA22LHABCEGPwDe-OHGyIaQuAHMKAJVaRuwaTAAUMUDABccLDCjsaGgDQJsOAPxXKNACbAm94G84AB84GkoREQBKKwAFRgBbdixgAB4bOwcAPkVlLFV1LRhdLH0Uo1NzKwz7JxdcK0xcfBQYuHiIJJT021qAbQBdHKUVNU0dPS5ymUqQS2teh2cYVw90VxbUUK9ffxpAkLCI6LjE5LSah0PLjUHhuAUlJXIqWmUAdwx2eEgbHszbgNrosNFljFFcgBffjQ-hMLxCGCcOi-GCpNBgtodLppDHyXIvah0bHnAB05CwEBEADdgMYSCQ8ugIbChFN4AAjGRwYj7d5SGYQ-hcmCkoolMqGGYkMw2EgQgD0CqUAD03MKZGKJqUplKTDLWDASM4dn4At5Fcq4GqNaLxZMDBUDXLnOFIpbVeqRVrig7pvrZUbnGQKET6IwWGxkTwPda3EA)

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, я не смог в комментарии поместить ссылку, добавил в вопрос. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Да, именно об этом и была речь в прошлом разговоре. Самый последний метод учитывает все вышеуказанные варианты, но так как мы передаем заранее известные константы, TS выведет одну из вышеуказанных сигнатур.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, я не сильно разбираюсь в TS и особенно с перезагрузками работаю впервые. Последний вариант мне нравится намного больше, чем с `extends`. Спасибо за помощь.